# docker rocketmq FileNotFoundException: /etc/rocketmq/broker.conf (Permission denied)

Tags: docker

docker run is following :

```
docker create -p 10911:10911 -p 10909:10909 --name rmqbroker \
-e "JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.home=/opt"  \
-e "JAVA_OPT_EXT=-server -Xms128m -Xmx128m -Xmn128m" \
-v  /haoke/rmq/rmqbroker/conf/broker.conf:/etc/rocketmq/broker.conf \
-v  /haoke/rmq/rmqbroker/logs:/opt/logs \
-v  /haoke/rmq/rmqbroker/store:/opt/store \
foxiswho/rocketmq:broker-4.3.2
```

but the log is following :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/rocketmq/broker.conf (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your system is centos7， Maybe it's because your permissions are disabled by the selinux of the system.
You can try to add parameter to the startup command

```
--privileged=true
```

or use command to shut down selinux

```
setenforce 0
```

Execute after starting your docker command

```
setenforce 1
```

But there are new problems

```
Exited (253) 48 seconds ago
```

and no any log

Comment: But there are new problems
 Exited (253) 48 seconds ago

Comment: I'm sorry, there's nothing I can do. Maybe you can try to check the configuration file.

Comment: Problem solved. It's a permission problem.chown -R 3000:3000 /haoke/rmq/rmqbroker

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
chown -R 3000:3000 /haoke/rmq/rmqbroker
```

Comment: What does `-R 3000:3000` mean, and why would changing ownership promise to group&user 3000 help? See also [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67814994/docker-rocketmq-filenotfoundexception-etc-rocketmq-broker-conf-permission-den/73767455#comment119894793_67815109).